# Send broadcast with unknown port

Tags: c#, .net, networking, udp, broadcast

Is it possible, to send a broadcast for searching a server application, if i don't know the port on which the server is running? Or do i have to check every port?

To send a simple broadcast, i found the following code at the internet:

**Server**

```
Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
Console.Write("Running server..." + Environment.NewLine);
server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 48000));

while (true)
{
    IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    EndPoint tempRemoteEP = (EndPoint)sender;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];

    server.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref tempRemoteEP);

    Console.Write("Server got '" + buffer[0] + "' from " + tempRemoteEP.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

    Console.Write("Sending '2' to " + tempRemoteEP.ToString() +
    Environment.NewLine);

    server.SendTo(new byte[] { 2 },
    tempRemoteEP);
}
```

**Client**

```
Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

IPEndPoint AllEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 48000);

//Allow sending broadcast messages
client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);

//Send message to everyone
client.SendTo(new byte[] { 1 }, AllEndPoint);
Console.Write("Client send '1' to " + AllEndPoint.ToString() +
Environment.NewLine);

IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
EndPoint tempRemoteEP = (EndPoint)sender;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];

string serverIp;

try
{
    //Recieve from server. Don't wait more than 3000 milliseconds.
    client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
    SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 3000);
    client.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref tempRemoteEP);
    Console.Write("Client got '" + buffer[0] + "' from " +
    tempRemoteEP.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

    //Get server IP (ugly)
    serverIp = tempRemoteEP.ToString().Split(":".ToCharArray(), 2)[0];
}
catch
{
    //Timout. No server answered.
    serverIp = "?";
}

Console.Write("ServerIp: " + serverIp + Environment.NewLine);
Console.ReadLine();
```

But I don't know, wehter my server use port `48000`.

Answer (score 0):

To send a broadcast:

```
var port = 123;
var udp = new UdpClient();
var data = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
udp.Send(data, data.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
```

If you don't know the port, you have to try all ports, which I do not recommend, since you're spamming the network.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you, i've writte an Application Server, which will deliver all data to the client. And since the customers install the clients on there own, i want to implement a kind of "Server Search" function, so that they only have to select the Application Server from a list.

Comment: So just use port 48000 by default. Scanning all 65000 ports of a host in a network might not only be slow, it also might not please the network administrator since this behavior loads the network and also might alert some intrusion detection systems.